# Does software in a professional environment need to be licensed?

Tags: licensing

**Background**: I'm writing in-house software - it has absolutely no contact with the world outside the company - but I'm using various libraries, which themselves do have some license structure. So for example GPL requires that software that re-uses the a GPL-licensed piece of code, to also be under GPL-license. Does that require my in-house application to have an explicit GPL-license, or is this understood implicitly? Does using AGPL-licensed code, require my code to be available to co-workers who use the in-house system?

**Question**: Does my in-house software need to have an explicit license, to be compliant with the licenses of such libraries? In what cases does in-house software need to have its own license?

Comment: contact the legal department of your company, it's them that will have to deal with the fallout of this type of screw-up

Comment: I think this part of the GPL FAQ pretty clear: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLRequireSourcePostedPublic, it should answer your question.

Comment: Why not just explicitly license it anyway? That will clear up any confusion other workers now or in the future when you've left will have.

Comment: @James - because creating an explicit license is more work, and if work can be avoided... you know how this continues :) A license needs to be validated by the Legal dept - and before I get them involved I better have a good reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [GPL FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLRequireSourcePostedPublic):

> **Does the GPL require that source code of modified versions be posted
>   to the public?**
>
> The GPL does not require you to release your modified version, or any part of it. You are free to make modifications and use them
>   privately, without ever releasing them. This applies to organizations
>   (including companies), too; an organization can make a modified
>   version and use it internally without ever releasing it outside the
>   organization.
>
> But if you release the modified version to the public in some way, the GPL requires you to make the modified source code available to the
>   program's users, under the GPL.

So your program that uses GPL code does not need to have a specific license as long as it is used only internally. However, "internally" ends when it [runs on a public server](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#UnreleasedMods):

> However, putting the program on a server machine for the public to
>   talk to is hardly “private” use, so it would be legitimate to require
>   release of the source code in that special case. Developers who wish
>   to address this might want to use the GNU Affero GPL for programs
>   designed for network server use.

Note that the wording implies this is a corner case and a court might not uphold this view.

Comment: And I Am Not A Lawyer!

Comment: +1 You can run GPL code on a public server without having to release your source. But AGPL is different: if you run AGPL code on a public server, you must release your source to the public. That's the difference between GPL and AGPL.

Comment: Example: When you run your website on a modified LAMP (Linux+Apache+MariaDB+PHP) stack, you don't have to publish the sourcecode of any of these components on your website.